# NLP how to get vectors of phrases/documents

Tags: nlp, word2vec, fasttext

I want to know how to generate vectors using NLP, if I'm not mistaken it should be done by sum or average of all words. However, it is not clear to me how the following sentences will generate different vectors using FastText:

```
phrase 1 : "Hello user, it's computer"
phrase 2 : "Hello computer, it's user"
```

Since all the words are same, I wonder how NLP models (especially FastText since I generate my model with it) will generate different vectors for these phrases. I also couldn't find any information on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

Using an average of all the words' vectors is one very-simple approach that can be used.

However, as you've noticed, since it has no understanding of grammar or word order, it's a pretty weak approach that will miss many kinds of meaning.

Still, it may be OK as a quick-and-easy baseline, especially for some simple topical-classification tasks that are often less sensitive to shades of meaning from longer phrases.

Other deep/recurrent text models can create summary vectors from texts that are sensitive to the compositional effects of words-in-order. [BERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BERT_(language_model)) is one well-documented model of that style that you could read about to understand more, or use as a starting point to find other alternatives.

Comment: Can doc2vec do such task as well? I'll start to search about BERT right now.

Comment: A couple of different approaches have ben called 'doc2vec`. If you mean the 'Paragraph Vectors' algorithm – which goes by the name `Doc2Vec` in the Python Gensim library & some other places – then it's a *slightly* more-sophisticated approach than a simple vector average, which trains a doc-vector as if it were a synthetic extra word floating over the whole text. But it still doesn't capture subtleties of ordering/grammar and strings-of-words that modify each others' meaning - that's something it takes deeper/recurrent networks to capture.